# Аналоги Сonsole.WriteLine() в С++

Tags: c#, c++, замена

Как записать данный вывод в С++? Важно сохранить места подстановки

```
string sc,sb;
....   
Console.WriteLine("{0}|  {1} | ", sc, sb);
```

Comment: Через функцию printf

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, этот момент я понял, а как сохранить места подстановки? Можно конкретный пример?

Comment: Можно вы сначала почитаете документацию на этот самый printf?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов `printf` это не плюсы. Но документации читать всё равно полезно :)

Comment: для форматированной подстановки: boost::format

Comment: @Marchosias Наиболее близкая по функция форматирования эта [либа](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt). Но самостоятельно она не умеет выводить на консоль,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << sc << "|  " << sb << " | " << endl;
```

Или

```
cout << sc << "|  " << sb << " | \n";
```

Результат аналогичен вашему.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << sc << "|";
cout << sb << "|";
```

`cout` в C++ выполняет вывод на консоль.

Comment: Ещё видимо перевод строки нужен. Ну и вертикальные полосы, если нужны ТСу.